# Why can't you call a non-static method from a static method within the same class?(Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field)

Tags: java, static, instance, non-static

In Java we can use

- non-static variables inside non-static methods without creating an
  instance within the same class.
- static variables inside non-static methods without having an issue within the same class.
- static variables inside a static a static method without having any issue within the same class.

I just want to know why we can not use a **non static variable inside a static method within the same class.**

Comment: What do you think `static` means in Java?

Answer (score -1):

It wouldn't make sense. Static methods are about belonging to the class, rather than individual instances. So, they don't have access to any instance (i.e. you can't use `this`™ inside them).

Things that aren't `static` are bound to individual instances.